# Sql naming best practice

Tags: sql

I'm not entirely sure if there's a standard in the industry or otherwise, so I'm asking here.

I'm naming a ***Users*** table, and I'm not entirely sure about how to name the members.

`user_id` is an obvious one, but I wonder if I should prefix all other fields with "user_" or not.

user_name
user_age

or just name and age, etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

prefixes like that are pointless, unless you have something a little more arbitrary; like two addresses.  Then you might use address_1, address_2, address_home, etc

Same with phone numbers.

But for something as static as age, gender, username, etc; I would just leave them like that.

Just to show you
If you WERE to prefix all of those fields, your queries might look like this

```
SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE users.user_name = "Jim"
```

When it could easily be

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = "Jim"
```

Comment: +1: For most of it, with a twist.  For ID's (like user_id) we ALWAYS spell out the full name, for everything else we do not prepend the table name.  Makes joins easier to read.

Comment: "gender... I would just leave them like that" -- more likely to be 'sex' (specifically male and female) for which there is an industry standard code [ISO 5218](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218), rather than gender (masculine, feminine, plus others).

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the other answers that suggest against prefixing the attributes with your table names.

However, I support the idea of using matching names for the foreign keys and the primary key they reference<sup>1</sup>, and to do this you'd normally have to prefix the `id` attributes in the dependent table.

Something which is not very well known is that SQL supports a concise joining syntax using the `USING` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id int, first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE sales (sale_id int, purchase_date datetime, user_id int);
```

Then the following query:

```
SELECT s.*, u.last_name FROM sales s JOIN users u USING (user_id);
```

is equivalent to the more verbose and popular joining syntax:

```
SELECT s.*, u.last_name FROM sales s JOIN users u ON (u.user_id = s.user_id);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not always possible. A typical example is a `user_id` field in a `users` table, and  `reported_by` and `assigned_to` fields in the referencing table that both reference the `users` table. Using a `user_id` field in such situations is both ambiguous, and not possible for one of the fields.

Comment: Although I don't see a problem with columns named "reported_by" and "assigned_to", you could call them "reported_by_user_id" and "assigned_to_user_id" if you want to make it more explicit what column they refer to.

Comment: @Obi: Yes, but my point was that it would still not be possible to use the `USING` syntax for such situations.

Answer (score 5):

As other answers suggest, it is a personal preference - pick up certain naming schema and stick to it.
Some 10 years ago I worked with Oracle Designer and it uses naming schema that I like and use since then:

- table names are plural - USERS
- surrogate primary key is named as singular of table name plus '_id' - primary key for table USERS would be "USER_ID". This way you have consistent naming when you use "USER_ID" field as foreign key in some other table
- column names don't have table name as prefix.

Optionally:

- in databases with large number of tables (interpret "large" as you see fit), use 2-3 
  characters table prefixes so that you can logically divide tables in areas. For example: all tables that contain sales data (invoices, invoice items, articles) have prefix "INV_", all tables that contain human resources data have prefix "HR_". That way it is easier to find and sort tables that contain related data (this could also be done by placing tables in different schemes and setting appropriate access rights, but it gets complicated when you need to create more than one database on one server)

Again, pick naming schema you like and be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Just go with name and age, the table should provide the necessary context when you're wondering what kind of name you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it as an entity and name the fields accordingly

I'd suggest a **User** table, with fields such as id, name, age, etc.

A group of *records* is a bunch of users, but the group of *fields* represents a user.

Thus, you end up referring to `user.id`, `user.name`, `user.age` (though you won't always include the table name, depending on the query).

Answer (score 2):

For the table names, I usually use pluralized nouns (or noun phrases), like you.

For column names I'd not use the table name as prefix. The table itself specifies the context of the column.

Answer (score 1):

It's personal preference. The best advice we can give you is consistency, legibility and ensuring the relationships are correctly named as well.

Use names that make sense and aren't abbreviated if possible, unless the storage mechanism you are using doesn't work well with them.

In relationships, I like to use Id on the primary key and [table_name]_Id on the foreign key. eg. Order.Id and OrderItem.Order_Id

It works well if using a surrogate key as a primary key.

Your storage mechanism may or may not be case sensitive, so be sure to that into account.

Edit: Also, there is some theory to suggest that the table should be named after what a single record in that table should represent. So, table name "User" instead of "Users" - personally the plural makes more sense to me, just keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest using the singular noun, i.e. **user** instead of **users**, although this is more of a personal preference.

Second, there are some who prefer to always name the primary key column **id**, instead of **user_id** (i.e. *table name + id*), and similar with for example **name** instead of **employee_name**. I think this is a bad idea for the following reason:

```
-- when every table has an "id" (or "name") column, you get duplicate column names in the output:
select e.id, e.name, d.id, d.name
from employee e, department d
where e.department_id = d.id

-- to avoid this, you need to specify column aliases every time you query:
select e.id employee_id, e.name employee_name, d.id department_id, d.name department_name
from employee e, department d
where e.department_id = d.id

-- if the column name includes the table, there are no conflicts, and the join condition is very clear
select e.employee_id, e.employee_name, d.department_id, d.department_name
from employee e, department d
where e.department_id = d.department_id
```

I'm not saying you should include the table name in every column in the table, but do it for the key (id) column and other "generic" columns such as name, description, remarks, etc. that are likely to be included in queries.

Answer (score 1):

table users (plural):

- id
- name
- age

plain and simple.

Comment: Agree. Except that `id` or `user_id` is a subject to discuss. Because if you have queries with a lot of joins and each table has column `ID` - you can easily be confused.

Comment: @abatishchev As is singular vs plural.  Many data modelers will say that it should be singular, since the collection of fields represents one entity. That is, what does 1 row in a table of user records represent?  It represents 1 user.

Comment: @George Marian: Yea and table represents all users

Comment: @abatishchev Right, which is why this debate continues and may never be settled.  If you look at a table as a collection of rows -- which generally is correct -- you probably favor pluralized names.  On the other hand, if you look at a table as a set of entity attributes and the collection of rows in that table as a group of entities with said attributes, you understand my point.  Another way to look at it: When you join a user table with some other table(s), you're associating a representation of one user at a time with one or more entities, represented by another table(s).

Comment: Ultimately, it's redundant to pluralize the table name.  If you know anything about using a database, you know that there will generally be multiple records in a table.  But, if each record only represent 1 entity, there is no need to state that again by pluralizing the table name.  Basically, you're focusing on the implementation, not the representation.

Comment: @George Marian: Agree! :) Personally I use plural form for sp-based SQL solutions and singular for ORM

Answer (score 1):

I think table and column names must be like that.

**Table Name :** 
*User* --> Capitalize Each Word and not plural.
**Column Names :** 
*Id* --> If i see "Id" I understand this is PK column. 

*GroupId* --> I understanding there is an table which named Group and this column is relation column for Group table.

*Name* --> If there is a column which named "Name" in User table, this means name of user. It's enaughly clear.

Especially if you are using Entity Framework I suppose this more.

**Note:** Sorry for my bad English. If somebody will correct my bad English i will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly named my columns using a prefix that was related to the table

```
i.e. table = USERS, column name = user_id, user_name, user_address_street, etc.
```

before that, when i started using JOINS I had to alias the crap out of the column names to avoid conflict in the query results, and then when accessed from templates in a MVC View, if the query result field name didn't match the published db schema, the template designers would get all confused and have to ask for the SQL VIEW to determine the correct field name to use.

So it looks messy to use a prefix in a column name, but in practice it works better for us.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not entirely sure if there's a standard in the industry

Yes: [ISO 11179-5: Naming and identification principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11179), available [here](http://metadata-standards.org/11179/).