# SQL id column with underscore or period

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I create tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar (32),
  email varchar (255)
)
```

A `SELECT` query with a `JOIN` would then look like this (I have to use periods here, because the id column exists in both tables):

```
SELECT account.id, name 
FROM account 
JOIN activity ON activity.account_id = account.id
```

I have seen others create tables with the table name in the column name for the id included (separated by an underscore):

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  account_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar (32),
  email varchar (255)
)
```

The query would then look like this:

```
SELECT account_id, name 
FROM account 
JOIN activity ON activity.account_id = account.account_id
```

Are there any benefits of using the underscore variant? Is there a performance difference? Is there any best practice about this subject?

Comment: There is no performance difference. What you choose is up to you - but be consistent.

Comment: No performance difference, only personal preference.

Comment: The second query isn't syntactically the same as the first. In the first the `account.`is qualifying the column, in the second `account_`is part of the name and that query would fail as the column name `account_id`is ambiguous. The second query should use `account.account_id`to be correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql naming best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328162/sql-naming-best-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the full identifier name makes it possible to use the `using` clause which makes the identifier unambiguous

```
select account_id, name
from
    account
    inner join
    activity using (account_id)
```

Your second query will error with an ambiguous name

```
SELECT account_id, name 
FROM account JOIN activity ON activity.account_id = account.account_id
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM

Another advantage of the full name is when you want the ids from more than one table to be used by a client. If the identifiers are named just `id` it  will be necessary to create aliases:

```
select
    account.id as account_id,
    activity.id as activity_id,
    name 
from
    account 
    inner join
    activity on activity.account_id = account.id
```

Comment: I think the `using` clause is a clear advantage for the full identifier name. I would have used the notation with period if I had not see this.
Why are you using `INNER JOIN` in this query? Is this required?

Comment: @wonderbummer It is not required to use `inner join` in instead of just `join`. But it is in my own book of good practices as it is clearer.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Typo in the first query: `on using` -> `using` (too short to edit...)

Answer (score 1):

There would not be any performance difference.  The only *practical* difference I can think of is that you won't have to type out the full column name on *every* query - only those that join to tables with ambiguous column names.

Another thing that may help you is table aliases:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    name 
FROM account a 
JOIN activity b
ON a.id = b.account_id
```

But other than that it's purely personal preference.  I've seen teams that use both as "standards" for various reasons.  I would guess that programmers prefer shorter names for less typing while admins prefer explicit names for more context when troubleshooting.